# Apply function only on NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

There are 3 columns A, B, C

```
A = [1,2,5,4,3,1]
B = ["yes","No","hello","yes","no", 'why']
C = [1,0,1,'NaN',0,0]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C})

def def_c(inB):
    if inB.Lower() == 'no':
        cis = 0
    else:
        cis = 1
        
    return cis
```

The general rule is that if B is equal to `no` then `cis` equals `0` using the defined function. However, this should only occur if C is NaN, as some times this rule is violated and considered to be true.

The expected dataframe output is
A

```
 = [1,2,5,4,3,1]
B = ["yes","No","hello","yes","no", 'why']
C = [1,0,1,1,0,0]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C})
```

What is the best way to iterate over the dataframe and apply the function if C is NaN. Is this best applied using pandas functions or using sklearn's `impute` ability?

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is` and `np.where`:

```
# assuming `NaN` is actual NA value
isna = test_df['C'].isna()
# or in the case of string `'NaN` as in sample
# isna = test_df['C'].eq('NaN')

test_df.loc[isna, 'C'] = np.where(test_df.loc[isna, 'B'].str.lower()=='no', 0, 1)

# or
# test_df.loc[isna, 'C'] = [def_c(inB) for inB in test_df.loc[isna, 'B'] ]
```

Output:

```
   A      B  C
0  1    yes  1
1  2     No  0
2  5  hello  1
3  4    yes  1
4  3     no  0
5  1    why  0
```

Comment: is this possible using the defined def_c() function?

Comment: when I run that and then again call test_df this is the output

A B C
0 1 yes 1
1 2 No 0
2 5 hello 1
3 4 yes NaN
4 3 no 0
5 1 why 0

Comment: the NaN value is still apearing

Comment: Did you try `isna = test_df['C'].eq('NaN')` as commented instead?